# How to install a gui for remote desktop on server 18.04?

Tags: server, ssh, gui, remote

I am a new user to Ubuntu server and trying to install a lightweight GUI on my server via SSH - so that i can remote in via a Windows 10 machine.

Is this possible or have i misread some of the information i've found online?

I'm aware that it is a less efficient way to use my resources, but it would be very helpful for me to get to grips with the operating system

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

**Simple**

Use this command:

```
$ sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I ran on my clean 18.04 server to get RDP GUI:

```
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
$ sudo add-apt-repository universe
$ sudo apt install tasksel
$ sudo tasksel install xubuntu-core
$ sudo service lightdm start
$ sudo apt install xrdp
$ sudo systemctl enable xrdp
```

You can substitute the xubuntu-core/lightdm for other desktops if you prefer.